# want to save the product image from csv file

Tags: magento

I want to import Configurable Product along with their associative products and images.
I imported the products it associative products are coming in configurable product but images are not uploaded for product.
can anyone help me out??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upload images for product from csv file you have to do these following-

1. make a directory named as "import" inside /media 
     /media/import.
2. You have to make 2 folders inside the media/import which depends on image name for ex- your image file name is "filename.jpg" then you make folder name "f" and inside this you have to make a directory named as "i" and inside this you have to put your image "filename.jpg"
   so, - media/import/f/i/filename.jpg
3. next you have to make changes in your csv file - 
   give path of image in these columns - image, small_image, thumbnail, _media_image. 
   Image path should be like this - /f/i/filename.jpg
4. Next define 
   "_media_attribute_id" set it as 88, 
   _media_lable
   _media_position
   _media_is_disabled  0 for not 1 for yes.